# flask returning json of arrar of array

Tags: python, arrays, json, flask

My flask api returns data that is hard to work with in JS on the front end.

Here is endpoint:

```
class BilagList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM bilag"
        result = cursor.execute(query)
        row = result.fetchall()
        return {'bilag': row}
```

Here is the result:

```
{
"bilag": 
[
[1, "description", "price", null], 
[2, "2description", "2price", null], 
[22, "Her er Serenas f\u00f8rste bilag!", "1000", "Serena"], 
[23, "Her er Admins f\u00f8rste bilag!", "1000", "admin"]
]
}
```

I would like to have just:

```
[1, "description", "price", null], 
[2, "2description", "2price", null], 
[22, "Her er Serenas f\u00f8rste bilag!", "1000", "Serena"], 
[23, "Her er Admins f\u00f8rste bilag!", "1000", "admin"]
```

Then I could just loop trough the array with js.

I could remove 
    {
    "bilag": 
    }

, by just returning row, but how would I get rid of the last pair of [] ?
And would there be any good reason why not to do that?

BR Kresten

Comment: Try `return {'bilag': row[0]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `str(row)[1:-1]` but instead take a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript)